# How can I find the default PlotTheme, and default plotting colors, for the current StyleSheet?

Tags: plotting, color, stylesheet, plot-themes

I like the new `Callout` facility in *Mathematica* 11, but it's still quite clunky.

One of the issues I have is that I often like to have my labels in the same color as the corresponding curve in my plot. It would be great if `CallOut` had an option so it would color the labels the same as the curves that are being labeled, but that doesn't seem to be a built-in option.

So I do something like,

```
Plot[{Callout[Sin[x], Sin[x], 5, 
   LabelStyle -> Directive[ColorData[97, 1]], 
   CalloutMarker -> "Circle"], 
  Callout[Cos[x], Cos[x], 5.5, 
   LabelStyle -> Directive[ColorData[97, 2]], 
   CalloutMarker -> "Circle"]}, {x, 0, 2 π}, 
 GridLines -> Automatic, PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
 PlotRangePadding -> {{0, 0}, {0.1, 0.1}}]
```

which happens to work fine in the standard environments.

However, right now I am in the process of putting together a slideshow, and it turns out that *Mathematica* uses a slightly different plot theme based on which slideshow template is chosen.

I have no idea how to even find out what the plot theme is, and I have even less of a clue how to find out what `ColorData` would correspond to that theme. My attempts to figure things out through the OptionInspector have failed, unfortunately.

Anyhow can anyone tell me how I could find the correct `ColorData` call above? By poking around with

```
Short[ColorData[n, "ColorList"], 4]
```

I managed to guess that I should now use `Colordata[98,n]`, but it would be really nice if there was a systematic way to figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thereof are a lot of interesting symbols in this context

```
Names["System`PlotThemeDump`*"] // Shallow
(* {"System`PlotThemeDump`a", 
"System`PlotThemeDump`aapl", "System`PlotThemeDump`all", 
"System`PlotThemeDump`allowmicroranges", 
"System`PlotThemeDump`angle", "System`PlotThemeDump`angle$", 
"System`PlotThemeDump`arg", "System`PlotThemeDump`att", 
"System`PlotThemeDump`axis", "System`PlotThemeDump`axisinfront", 
<<272>>} *)
```

Looking through the names, it seems that this is the one you want

```
System`PlotThemeDump`$ThemeStylesheetIndexed
```

This variable is initialized only after you've evaluated a plot in a given `StyleSheet`.  After staring a new slide show, having chosen a given template, you can find out the default indexed colors via

```
System`PlotThemeDump`$ThemeStylesheetIndexed
Plot[{x, x + 1}, {x, 0, 3}]
System`PlotThemeDump`$ThemeStylesheetIndexed
ColorData[%, "ColorList"]
```

[image]

Not ideal, but this will give you the color list you are looking for.

Comment: Excellent, this works fine. Thanks!

Comment: @Pirx - glad I could help.  Also, feel free to revert the edits I made on the original question, just wanted to make the title more specific so it can help future users who do a search for this topic

Comment: I looked at your edits, and they're fine. You did remove some of my more colorful language, but that's fine, too ;-)

Comment: Interestingly, on my machine `` System`PlotThemeDump`$ThemeStylesheetIndexed `` has the value `{}`, no matter what stylesheet I choose. (Win7, *Mathematica* 11.1.0.0)